# Place text below kanban image?

Tags: odoo

I am writing a custom module to give an broad overview of the health of the PCs on a network.  The kanban view is simply a red, yellow, or green light along with the IP address.  I would like the IP address to be centered below image, but currently in only shows up on the right side of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I figured it out after posting the question.  :/

One way, at least, is to enclose the IP address field in its own `<div>`